# Wordpress Insert Query not working

Tags: mysql, wordpress, insert

I am creating web services for an App, but I am stuck with a insert query. Actually I made a rating system and want to insert value in database with wordpress standard.

Here is my query:

```
$res = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
                "INSERT INTO $table_name(rating_postid, rating_posttile, rating_rating, rating_username, rating_userid) VALUES (%d, %s, %d, %s, $d )", 
                    array(
                        $rating_postid, 
                        $post_title, 
                        $post_rating,
                        $user_name,
                        $rating_userid
                    ) 
                ) 
            );
```

and here is the other one:

```
$res = $wpdb->insert(
                $table_name,
                array(
                    'rating_postid' => $rating_postid,
                    'rating_posttile' => $post_title,
                    'rating_rating' => $post_rating,
                    'rating_username' => $user_name,
                    'rating_userid' => $rating_userid
                )
            );
```

But no one is working, why?

```
if($res){
        echo 'inserted';
    }else{
        echo 'not inserted';
    }
```

I am getting else part alwasy

I used these queries very often and they worked me very well, But I am not sure what's wrong with them now... :(

Comment: Too many bees or candles, or something! No seriously, you've given us next to nothing that we can work with. What errors are you getting? How are you incorporating this code? Where is the rest of your code? What is the rest of your code?

Comment: Updated the post. There is no error while I am running this. I am just want to know if the query is correct or not?

Comment: @ManishNegi your query is correct.

Comment: @ManishNegi To answer that we need context! Since you say your query isn't doing what you want, the answer would presumably be 'NO'. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
        $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            array(
                'rating_postid' => $rating_postid,
                'rating_posttile' => $post_title,
                'rating_rating' => $post_rating,
                'rating_username' => $user_name,
                'rating_userid' => $rating_userid
            ),
            array( 
                '%d',
                '%s', 
                '%s', 
                '%s', 
                '%d' 
            ) 
        );
```

Comment: add this before insert query `$wpdb->show_errors();`.  and add this `exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) );` after insert query

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring **`$wpdb`** as global and using it to execute an SQL query statement that returns a PHP object

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "YOUR_TABLE_NAME";    // Enter without prefix
$data = array(
    'rating_postid' => $rating_postid,
    'rating_posttile' => $post_title,
    'rating_rating' => $post_rating,
    'rating_username' => $user_name,
    'rating_userid' => $rating_userid
);

$result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data);
if( $result ){
    echo "Inserted..!";
}else{
    echo "Something wrong..!";
    $wpdb->show_errors();
}
```

Comment: @ManishNegi have you set this field `rating_postid` as a primary key?

Comment: @ManishNegi add this line `$wpdb->show_errors();` in `else` statement.

Comment: No 'rating_postid' is not not primary key. Primary key is 'rating_id' which is auto_increment in table